# How can I bring an actor to front in clutter

Tags: c, clutter

In my clutter program written in c I have two Textures that overlap. One of them stays the same while the program is running and the other moves in to overlap from somewhere else on the stage. Because the second texture was created after the first one, it covers part of it up, but I want the first Texture to stay on top. How can I do this? The only way I can think of doing it is deleting the first Texture and making a new one using exactly the same picture every time a new Texture overlaps it, but this seems very inefficient to me. Is there a function that brings an actor to the front using the clutter API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `clutter_actor_raise()` and `clutter_actor_lower()`:

http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterActor.html#clutter-actor-raise

if the actors belong to the same container.